# Find first interval containing a given number in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Find first interval containing a given number in a DataFrame.

The DataFrame with each row representing an interval `<start, stop>`:

```
   start  stop
0      1     4
1      2     7
2      4    10
3      4    12
4      5    14
5      6    10
```

If I were looking for `8`, I should get row no. 2, because this is the first interval to contain 8 (`start <= 8 <= stop`).

```
   start  stop
0      1     4
1      2     7
2      4    10   # <--- the first one to contain 8
3      4    12
4      5    14
5      6    10
```

I was trying with `np.searchsorted`, but I can only search for `start` value... I don't want to use some `.iterrows()` stuff, because **performance is crucial**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.argmax`

```
>>> np.argmax((df['start'].values <= 8) & (8 <= df['stop'].values))
2
```

**Performance**

```
%timeit np.argmax((df['start'].values <= 8) & (8 <= df['stop'].values))
9.31 µs ± 559 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit (df["start"].le(8) & df["stop"].ge(8)).idxmax()
382 µs ± 4.52 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: That works! Thanks for the answer and the time comparison :)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Series.idxmax` on our boolean series:

```
(df["start"].le(8) & df["stop"].ge(8)).idxmax()

# out: 2
```